# Any way to speed up this CTE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This query is taking 5 seconds:

```
With cte as 
(
    Select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order By dbo.GetLatestStatusDateTime(d.DocumentID)) peta_rn, d.DocumentID, d.IsReEfiled, d.IGroupID, d.ITypeID, d.RecordingDateTime,
        d.IDate, d.InstrumentID, d.DocumentStatusID, u.Username, j.JDAbbreviation, inf.DocumentName,  dbo.GetLatestStatusDateTime(d.DocumentID) as LatestStatusDatetime,
        it.Abbreviation as ITypeAbbreviation, d.DocumentDate, ds.Abbreviation as DocumentStatusAbbreviation 
                From Documents d Left Join IGroupes ig On d.IGroupID = ig.IGroupID 
                Left Join ITypes it On d.ITypeID = it.ITypeID 
                Left Join Users u On u.UserID = d.UserID 
                Left Join DocumentStatuses ds On d.DocumentStatusID = ds.DocumentStatusID 
                Left Join InstrumentFiles inf On d.DocumentID = inf.DocumentID 
                Left Join Jurisdictions j on j.JurisdictionID = d.JurisdictionID Where 1 = 1  And d.JurisdictionID = 1
)
Select  * from cte
                Where 1 = 1 
                And peta_rn>92000 AND peta_rn<=92100
```

Though this is a static query, it will be dynamic in the sense that `Order By` in `Row_Number()` would be based on what user selects. Eg. currently it is `dbo.GetLatestStatusDateTime(d.DocumentID)` but it can be anything else too. Hence this query would be generated in code using if and then. Anyways, can you spot any mistake in my query? Why would it take 5 seconds for mere 100 records? I have seen SQL server scale upto millions of records and this is just 1/10th of million and I am suffering from bottleneck :(

**Edit: Massive improvement**

Changing the query to this:

```
With cte as 
(

        Select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order By d.DocumentID) peta_rn, d.DocumentID
                From Documents d Left Join IGroupes ig On d.IGroupID = ig.IGroupID 
                Left Join ITypes it On d.ITypeID = it.ITypeID 
                Left Join Users u On u.UserID = d.UserID 
                Left Join DocumentStatuses ds On d.DocumentStatusID = ds.DocumentStatusID 
                Left Join InstrumentFiles inf On d.DocumentID = inf.DocumentID 
                Left Join Jurisdictions j on j.JurisdictionID = d.JurisdictionID Where 1 = 1  And d.JurisdictionID = 1
)
Select  d.DocumentID, d.IsReEfiled, d.IGroupID, d.ITypeID, d.RecordingDateTime,
        d.IDate, d.InstrumentID, d.DocumentStatusID, u.Username, j.JDAbbreviation, inf.DocumentName, 
        it.Abbreviation as ITypeAbbreviation, d.DocumentDate, ds.Abbreviation as DocumentStatusAbbreviation 
                From Documents d Left Join IGroupes ig On d.IGroupID = ig.IGroupID 
                Left Join ITypes it On d.ITypeID = it.ITypeID 
                Left Join Users u On u.UserID = d.UserID 
                Left Join DocumentStatuses ds On d.DocumentStatusID = ds.DocumentStatusID 
                Left Join InstrumentFiles inf On d.DocumentID = inf.DocumentID 
                Left Join Jurisdictions j on j.JurisdictionID = d.JurisdictionID
                Inner Join cte On cte.DocumentID = d.DocumentID
                And peta_rn>92000 AND peta_rn<=92100
```

executes the query in 1 second. But I still feel 1 second is too big just for 100 records. Any other optimizations please?

Comment: All those `LEFT OUTER JOIN` are killing you - I'm telling you (again) ..... try the CTE with the `ROW_NUMBER()` function just on your largest table - results should be almost instanteneous. Also: what are those functions (`dbo.GetLatestStatusDateTime`) doing?? Are they accessing the database?? That's another **massive** perf killer...

Comment: what are you doing in this function dbo.GetLatestStatusDateTime(d.DocumentID)).I guess this is the bottel neck

Comment: @marc_s: Can you please tell what do you mean by largest table? Any example? Do you mean I should first do Row_number over Documents table? That is the biggest one. Yes dbo.GetLatestStatusDateTime are accessing DB :(

Comment: @AnandPhadke: Even If I remove that, the results still take same time.

Comment: Run with `SET STATISTICS IO ON` and also display the actual execution plan, this should give you an idea of where the bottle neck is (unless it lies in your functions which i suspect it might). In your second query all the joins within the CTE are redundant, you only need the table `documents` since you only use `DocumentID` and `JurisdictionID`. Remove them and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this. It is alot of code to edit without knowing the tables relations and not being able to test it. I hope this helps.

```
With d as 
(
  Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order By d.DocumentID) peta_rn, 
  DocumentID, IsReEfiled, IGroupID, ITypeID, RecordingDateTime,
  IDate, InstrumentID, DocumentStatusID, JurisdictionID, UserID
  from Documents
)
Select  d.DocumentID, d.IsReEfiled, d.IGroupID, d.ITypeID, d.RecordingDateTime,
d.IDate, d.InstrumentID, d.DocumentStatusID, u.Username, j.JDAbbreviation, inf.DocumentName, 
it.Abbreviation as ITypeAbbreviation, d.DocumentDate, ds.Abbreviation as DocumentStatusAbbreviation 
From d Left Join IGroupes ig On d.IGroupID = ig.IGroupID 
Left Join ITypes it On d.ITypeID = it.ITypeID 
Left Join Users u On u.UserID = d.UserID 
Left Join DocumentStatuses ds On d.DocumentStatusID = ds.DocumentStatusID 
Left Join InstrumentFiles inf On d.DocumentID = inf.DocumentID 
Left Join Jurisdictions j on j.JurisdictionID = d.JurisdictionID
where
d.peta_rn>92000 AND d.peta_rn<=92100
```